# Copy a chart and a table from excel worksheet to an existing powerpoint slide 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a table and a chart from one worksheet "Account Performance" to existing powerpoint slide no. 2
there are three problems in the below mentioned code:
first problem,I have written two codes one to copy the table (by specifying the range) another to copy the chart but when I am running the code the table is pasted twice on the slide and its not pasting the chart. what did I do wrong?
second problem, position code set for chartobject is giving error
third problem, most of the times code does not give error but attimes code gives error on the below mentioned line:
pres.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste

Please find  below the code:

```
Sub latestppu()
  Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim preslide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim shapepp As PowerPoint.Shape
  Dim exappli As Excel.Application
  Dim exworkb As Workbook
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim myshape As Object
  Dim x As Integer

  x = 1

  Dim mychart As ChartObject
  Dim activechart As ChartObject
  Dim R As Integer
  Dim G As Integer
  Dim B As Integer

  'Open powerpoint application -
  Set exappli = New Excel.Application
  exappli.Visible = True

  'activate powerpoint application
  Set pptapp = New PowerPoint.Application

  pptapp.Visible = True
  pptapp.Activate

  'open the excel you wish to use

  Set exworkb = exappli.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\astha.verma\Desktop\Macro\Reference Sheet.xlsm")


  'open the presentation you wish to use
  Set pres = pptapp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\astha.verma\Desktop\Macro\PPTtemplate.pptx")

  'Add title to the first slide
  With pres.Slides(1)

    If Not .Shapes.HasTitle Then
       Set shapepp = .Shapes.AddTitle
    Else:
       Set shapepp = .Shapes.Title
    End If

    With shapepp
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Gulf+ Market Segment Analysis Report" & vbNewLine & "P5 Week 04 FY17"
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial Black"
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 24
      .TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
    End With
  End With

  'Add title to second slide
  With pres.Slides(2)
    If Not .Shapes.HasTitle Then
       Set shapepp = .Shapes.AddTitle
    Else:
       Set shapepp = .Shapes.Title
    End If

    With shapepp
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Gulf+ Account Performance"
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "EY Gothic Cond Demi"
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 22
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
      .TextEffect.FontBold = msoFalse
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      .TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentLeft
    End With
  End With

  'add a textbox

  Set shapepp = pres.Slides(2).Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=650, Top:=75, Width:=200, Height:=50)

  With shapepp
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Other Account Performance Metrics"
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "EY Gothic Cond Demi"
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignRight
    .TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End With

  'Copy a table range from account summary worksheet and paste it in powerpoint slide 2:-

  'defining the range
  Set rng = exworkb.Sheets("Account Performance").Range("A1:B5")

  'Copy excel range
  rng.Copy

  'paste to powerpoint slide 2
  '**attimes gives error on this line(did I do anything wrong)**
  pres.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste

  pptapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, msoTrue
  pptapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = -30
  pptapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 350

  On Error Resume Next

  'add a textbox

  Set shapepp = pres.Slides(2).Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=600, Top:=280, Width:=200, Height:=50)

  With shapepp
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "GTER by global account segment"
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "EY Gothic Cond Demi"
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignRight
    .TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End With

  'defining the second  chart to be copied
  Set mychart = exworkb.Sheets("Account Performance").ChartObjects

  'Copy first chart
  mychart.Chart.ChartObjects.Copy

  'paste to powerpoint slide 2
  pres.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste

  'position?
  With pres.Slides(2).Shapes(1)
    .Top = 165
    .Left = 200
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `On Error Resume Next` is that it not only helps bypass errors that you may have expected, but it also bypasses errors that make the code not work.

I don't know what the first two commands below do, but I think they're full of errors that you don't know about (because of the `Resume Next`), so nothing gets copied. The clipboard still contains the table, and that's what gets pasted.

```
'defining the second  chart to be copied
Set mychart = exworkb.Sheets("Account Performance").ChartObjects

'Copy first chart
mychart.Chart.ChartObjects.Copy

'paste to powerpoint slide 2
pres.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste
```

So why are you talking about first and second charts?

You should declare your variable mychart as a Chart, then assign it properly as a chart (which of the charts on "Account Performance" is it? I'm assuming 1), then copy it properly.

```
'define the chart to be copied
Set mychart = exworkb.Sheets("Account Performance").ChartObjects(1).Chart

'copy the chart
mychart.ChartArea.Copy

' inserted to help with timing errors
DoEvents

'paste to powerpoint slide 2
pres.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste
```

Comment: Thanks, now the chart is getting copied in the powerpoint second thing which I want to know if I need to position it. In case there wwas no specific slide the I would have used the below code but if I have to positioned it on slide two how shud I modify the below code:

Comment: preslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteHTML)


With preslide.Shapes(preslide.Shapes.Count)
        .Top = 65
        .Left = 72
        .Width = 700

Comment: and one more Issue at times code is running fine but attimes code is giving the following error: Run Time Error - 2147188160 (80048240) Shapes (unknown member): Invalid Request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here. It is coming on the below mentioned code

Comment: pres.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste

Comment: When I am trying to paste the range/table. I have removed the command on error resume next

Comment: Re Empty Clipboard. Sometimes when you copy an object (e.g., this chart) it takes longer for the object to be copied than for VBA to try to execute the next command (the paste). I've inserted `DoEvents` in the code between these two commands.

Comment: @astha I can't really make sense of your first two comments. Do you want to position the shape?